# SQL Query output print

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

i have a question... employee table is given below:

```
EmpID Name ManagerID
    1    a         2
    2    b         3
    3    c         4
    4    d         1
```

Desired result:

```
EmpID Name ManagerID ManagerName
    1    a         2 b
    2    b         3 c
    3    c         4 d
    4    d         1 a
```

Please help me out how to print the output.
Thanks

Comment: where is `managers name`  in other table . provide schema and some data

Comment: Do the inner join on table and you will get what you want.

Comment: there are no 2 different table...above is single table.

Comment: Post the details of the tables involved, insert statements as sample data and explain the rules to generate your desired output.

Comment: And decide if this is a MySQL or Oracle specific question...

Answer (score 1):

You will need a self join here since manager is also an employee

```
SELECT  e1.EmpID, e1.Name, e2.Name as ManagerName 
from employee as e1, employee as e2
where  e1.ManagerID=e2.EmpID
```

Comment: doesn't matter this is a simple inner join ... while in case of joins you may use inner, outer, left etc..inner join and the way I have written the solution both will perform cartesian product on the back-end and will filter the results based on WHERE and ON  respectively.

Comment: There is only one table

Comment: @Strawberry there is one table but the manger info is in another table since there isnt any name of manager in the table..Check the question please..

Comment: Um no, there is only one table. Managers are also Employees

Comment: I think we should discourage this join style

Comment: @Strawberry may i know the reason? since it performs cartesian on the back-end same as inner join... are you talking about self join or inner join??

Comment: I'm talking about comma-

Comment: this can be used for inner joins only..there isn't any difference in performance of both of the statements...

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.Name, t1.ManagerID, t2.Name as `Manager`
 FROM employee t1 JOIN employee t2 
      ON t1.ManagerID = t2.EmpID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `left join` on the same table. If some employee does not have a manager then doing `inner join` will not display them. So it would be as

```
select t1.*, t2.name as manager_name
from table_name t1
left join table_name t2 on t1.empid = t2.managerid
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do join between the two tables for example:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, m.id, m.name 
FROM employee e, manager m 
WHERE e.managerId=m.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select e.EmpID,  e.Name,  e.ManagerID,  m.Name 
from employee e
left join manager m
on e.ManagerID=m.ManagerID
```